# TopComponent resizing behavior

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-platform, jsplitpane

At the moment, when you try to manually resize a TopComponent, it will show a black line showing the future size of the TopComponent.

[image]

I'd like to know what is the `JComponent` behind this black line? And how can i access it?

---

**EDIT**

The first part of my question was answered. The component shown in the attached picture is a `JSplitPane`.

Right now, i'd like to be able to access it (i.e get the instance of the `JSplitPane`'s used for `TopComponent` resizing in the netbeans platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- there is [JSplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html),
- but not sure if Netbeans is compiled in Java (in compare with Eclipse)

  EDIT `I'd like to add a listener on it.`
- add PropertyChangeListener to the JSplitPane,
- there are a few usefull methods for `if (propertyName.equals(JSplitPane.XxxXxx))`
- notice for Nested JSplitPane, have to add listener for each of JSplitPanes separatelly
- for example

.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class JSplitPaneToy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, makePanel(), makePanel());
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 10, 10));
        pnl.add(makePanel());
        pnl.add(makePanel());
        pnl.add(makePanel());
        pnl.add(makePanel());
        PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener = new PropertyChangeListener() {

            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent changeEvent) {
                JSplitPane sourceSplitPane = (JSplitPane) changeEvent.getSource();
                String propertyName = changeEvent.getPropertyName();
                if (propertyName.equals(JSplitPane.LAST_DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY)) {
                    int current = sourceSplitPane.getDividerLocation();
                    System.out.println("Current: " + current);
                    Integer last = (Integer) changeEvent.getNewValue();
                    System.out.println("Last: " + last);
                    Integer priorLast = (Integer) changeEvent.getOldValue();
                    System.out.println("Prior last: " + priorLast);
                }else if (propertyName.equals(JSplitPane.RESIZE_WEIGHT_PROPERTY)) {
                    int current = sourceSplitPane.getDividerLocation();
                    System.out.println("Current: " + current);
                    Integer last = (Integer) changeEvent.getNewValue();
                    System.out.println("Last: " + last);
                    Integer priorLast = (Integer) changeEvent.getOldValue();
                    System.out.println("Prior last: " + priorLast);
                }
            }
        };
        sp.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSplitPane Toy");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 10));
        frame.add(sp);
        frame.add(pnl);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JScrollPane makePanel() {
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(new JTable(
                new Object[][]{{0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}, new Object[]{1, 2, 3}));
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        return pane;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yay, I think it's [JSplitPane.setContinuousLayout()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setContinuousLayout(boolean)).

Comment: Hm. Thanks. I guess it's written in java: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans. I'm wondering know if there is anything in the exposed API to get the JSplitPane used for top component resizing.

Comment: I'd like to add a listener on it.

Comment: @mKorbel thanks for the piece of code. I was aware the property listener but my problem atm is how to get the JSplitPane used by Netbeans RCP when resizing top components.